# Instafeed not loading

Tags: instagram, instafeedjs

hi I am trying to get an instagram feed onto my website showing my user photos. I have put the javascript at the top of my page as follows:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>tomsaxby.com</title>

<!-- CSS ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
<!-- Bootstrap --><!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- EDITS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">  
<!-- Fonts -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/neuzeit/MyFontsWebfontsKit.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- CSS ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/instafeed.min.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">
var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    userId: 904401907,
    accessToken: '904401907.1677ed0.27d4a579f194430cbe77c28af165aae1'
});
userFeed.run();
</script>
</head>
```

I have then put a div with he id of "instafeed" into the body of my page. but nothing displays either locally or when i upload my files? Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of your problem, is that instafeed.js is trying to run before your page has been completely loaded.

To resolve this, make sure you have put `<div id="instafeed"></div>` on your page, and that you are loading instafeed.js after the page has been completely loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var feed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'awesome',
    clientId: clientId
  });
  feed.run();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One other thing...something the instafeed page does NOT seem to mention...is to add a "limit"...this tells instagram how many images to drop in.. otherwise i suppose the default is zero...

I made mine: limit: '4'

would be a pretty helpful piece of info to put into the instructions!

see below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'cool',
        clientId: '916c01b8624d43c7b4b76369aruc86a0',
        limit: '4' 
    });
    feed.run(); </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `instafeed.js` file is not properly being called up.

You have put this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/instafeed.min.js"></script>
```

The `path/to/` before the `instafeed.min.js` needs to actually be a working path with your website info.